# Drawing a frame for a block including the title text

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, block, beamerposter

Using [`tcolorbox`](https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), in a `beamer` with `beamerposter`package, I need to create a new `boxedblock` environment.

```
\begin{boxedblock}{Motivation & Contributions}
    
\end{boxedblock}
```

Expected result:

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % mandatory for the block definition below

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Block definition
\setbeamertemplate{block begin} 
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block title}
        \vskip0pt
        \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
        \vskip-1.25ex
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    {\parskip0pt\par}
    \usebeamerfont{block body}
    \vskip-0.5ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block body}
        \justifying
        \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
        \vskip-2ex
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{block end}
    {
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0pt
    \vspace*{2ex}
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{block}{title}
        content
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

ps: both `tcolorbox` and `beamerposter` are dependencies that the MWE does not use but I do need them.

Comment: From your expected result image it looks like the content from the example is just ignored. Is that on purpose?

Comment: the content can be anything as long it is can fit in the block environment. I had to redact what was written inside. Please don't mind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % mandatory for the block definition below

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Block definition
\setbeamertemplate{block begin} 
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block title}
        \vskip0pt
        \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
        \vskip-1.25ex
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    {\parskip0pt\par}
    \usebeamerfont{block body}
    \vskip-0.5ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block body}
        \justifying
        \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
        \vskip-2ex
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{block end}
    {
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0pt
    \vspace*{2ex}
}

\newtcolorbox{boxedblock}[1]{
title=#1,
colframe=blue,
colback=white,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={size=small,colback=white,colframe=white},
coltitle=blue
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{boxedblock}{Motivation \& Contributions}
some test in here
\end{boxedblock}

    \begin{block}{title}
        content
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: the golden line`attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},` Thanks a lot!

Comment: @anis See section "10.2.3 Options for the Boxed Title Box" of the tcolorbox documentation for more gold like this :)

Comment: adding this: for coherence with the rest of the beamer theme, `title =#1,
 fonttitle =\usebeamerfont{block title},` provided `block title` is defined as a beamer font